# How to determine the return type of a function in template

Tags: c++, templates, return-type

I am trying to write a class similar to std::function, just to learn how it works but I am having problem determining the return type of the function.

I found [this](https://ideone.com/iZr2KH) from one of the answers here on stack overflow. I am trying to do something similar but It does not work and I do not know why.

```
template< class Fx >
class function
{
public:
    function() = default;

    function(Fx* fx)
    {
        this->fx = fx;
    }
        
    template < class... A >
    ReturnType operator()(A... args)
    {
        //return ((*fx)(args), ...); ??
    }

private:
    template<class F>
    struct return_type;

    template< class R, class... A>
    struct return_type<R(*)(A...)>
    {
        using type = R;
    };

    using ReturnType = return_type<Fx>::type;
    Fx* fx;
};


int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; };

int main()
{
    function<int(int, int)> mysum{ sum };
    mysum(10, 10);
}
```

It gives me an error on line

`using ReturnType = return_type<Fx>::type;`

saying incomplete type is not allowed. Why does it not pick the specialized one?

Comment: Does `int(int, int)` and `R(*)(A...)` match?

Comment: @NathanOliver Not sure what you mean. I thought R would be deduced to int and A... parameter pack would be deduced to int, int?

Comment: Sure, but what about the `*`?  Does the type you are giving the template have that in it?

Comment: Ahh yess, I see it now. New to all this syntax its hard to tell what's what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Fx` is supposed to be a function type, not a function pointer type, so the specialization should be declared as:

```
template< class R, class... A>
struct return_type<R(A...)>
{
    using type = R;
};
```

Other issues:

1. Change `using ReturnType = return_type<Fx>::type;` to `using ReturnType = typename return_type<Fx>::type;`.
2. Move the declaration of `ReturnType` (and definition of `return_type`) before using it as the return type of `operator()`.
3. Change `return ((*fx)(args), ...);` to `return (*fx)(args...);` in the `operator()`; i.e. all the arguments are supposed to be passed to `fx` instead of calling `fx` multiple times with each argument.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/62ms6jNVRxR8Megs)

BTW: [Return type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction) (since C++14) is worthy of consideration too. E.g.

```
template < class... A >
auto operator()(A... args)
{
    return (*fx)(args...);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bmKOK2csE7pwGGae)

Answer (score 2):

You should change your template in the class instantiation:

```cpp
template <typename R, typename ...Args>
class function {
    ...
    R operator()(Args... args){
        return fx(...args)
    }
}
```